# Old empirical research that is wrong in light of modern theoretical work

Tags: references

What are examples of published empirical studies that can be proven wrong in the light of more recent theoretical results?

Comment: Do you only want really old material, or would serious mistakes that are recent also interest you?

Comment: I guess I am interested in either! But, I'm more curious about really really old stuff that is known to be blatantly wrong only from a modern perspective (it was perceived to be robust in its time).

Comment: related: gking.harvard.edu/files/mist.pdf

Comment: I guess JSTOR could be a good place, but still you would have to know what to look for... http://www.jstor.org/action/showJournals#43693424

Comment: (+1) nico. Looking at these early 1800s statistics journals ... It would've been damn boring to be a statistician back then.

Comment: @PeterFlom I welcome you to provide examples of some serious present mistakes .. You've tickled my interest now :)

Comment: @Jase I think you should reorganize the question to read something like -- "What are examples of published empirical studies that can be shown to be incorrect in the light of more recent theoretical results?". I think that would make a _great_ CW.

Comment: I will try to find some in my books, tomorrow, when I get to the office. But there are lots.

Comment: Does the Bahadur-Savage impossibility result fit want you want? (It shows that, despite lots of prior work on non-parametric tests, it's impossible to guarantee having useful power unless one makes some assumptions, even with sane/nice sampling distributions)

Comment: @guest I am not interested only because I have no idea what this is and I don't currently have the time to learn... But you should post it if it fits in with the question's request, and you can be bothered contributing it.

Comment: @Peter Flom: Did you find some examples?